# Node.js Forever Ubuntu - cannot save file

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, forever

I have node.js project on Ubuntu. I have the ability to upload a picture to the server. When I start server from `node bin/www`, everything works fine. But when I try to start from Forever, server is running, but picture is not upload. In 
`var/log/myapp.log` there are no errors. I use:

1. node v0.12.7
2. forever v0.15.1

**EDIT:** This is the code file entry:

```
function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {
    var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
        response = {};
    if (matches.length !== 3) {
        return new Error('Invalid input string');
    }
    response.type = matches[1];
    response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');
    return response;
}

var login = req.session.login;
var time = Date.now();
originalName = login + time + '.png';
var target_path = 'public/uploads/' + originalName;
var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(photo);
fs.writeFileSync(target_path, imageBuffer.data);
```

Comment: It sounds like it's probably a dependency on the current directory being set appropriately, but there's no way for us to have any idea if that's it or how to fix it since you've disclosed no relevant code.  I'd say to look in your node.js code to see where you are assuming a particular current directory rather than using an absolute path.

Comment: @jfriend00, I add the code, but I think that's not the case, and in the access rights, because I start `node bin/www` from the root, project works fine. I guess, forever can't start project from the root.

Comment: Have you verify the logs from forever? there may be a permission issue

Comment: Ah yes, forever is probably not starting your server as root.  I had to work a bit on my server to get it to not require root permissions.

Comment: @David, logs is fine.

Comment: @jfriend00, you had work on Ubuntu server, or node server? Please, tell paths or file which I should edit, thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to make changes to both my node.js server code and to my Linux server configuration to get my server to run without root privileges under Forever.  For example, you can't even run a server listening to port 80 unless you're root so I had to make my server listen on 8000 and configure my Linux server to port forward port 80 to port 8000 using iptables.

Comment: @jfriend00, I started a server listening to port 3000, everything works except upload pictures, as well as on port 80. It's not a problem to start the server, but the picture not upload to server

Comment: You asked what changes I had to make to my server so I told you.  You probably have some other permission problem.  The code you have in your question does appear to assume a particular current directory since it writes to "public/uploads/filename" which is a relative path.  That would be my next suspect, but without the ability to do debugging, all we can do is guess.